# When I add an item into one recyclerview it gets two

Tags: android, copy, pass-by-reference, weak-references, strong-references

I think it's reference problem.

RecyclerViews seem they share items with the same reference.

I created two recyclerviews, And I make a list, and I send the list through a method to create another recyclerview.

For instance,

```
val myAdapter = MyAdapter()
val myList = ArrayList<String>()

val yourAdapter = MyAdapter()
val yourList: ArrayList<String>? = null

private fun init(){
    initAction()
    list.add("lion")
    list.add("cat")
    list.add("dog")
    myAdapter.setList(list)
    rcvMy.adapter = myAdapter
    
    initOtherRecyclerView(list)
}

private fun initOtherRecyclerView(mList: ArrayList<String>){
    yourList = mList
    yourAdapter.setList(yourList)
    rcvYour.adapter = yourAdapter
}

private fun initAction(){
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
        myAdapter.items.add("Hello")
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

whenever I click the `btnAdd`, it adds two items into `rcvMy`.

How can I cut the referencing?

Answer (score 0):

Both Adapter are holding same `List` you can use two separate Lists . And whenever you need a data from list you get it view the `Adapter`.
Below is an example with the example in question .

```
private fun initOtherRecyclerView(mList: ArrayList<String>){
    yourList.addAll(mList);
    yourAdapter.setList(yourList)
    rcvYour.adapter = yourAdapter
}
```

Comment: But aren't the Strings are the same  reference?

Comment: Yeah but you are not modifying String you are modifying the list .

Comment: I modify the list as well. Actually, It's not a String, but an Object. ex. Student Class.